# Strange Java Behavior Regarding Interfaces and Class Circular Dependency

Tags: java, class

I have the following code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Class.INSTANCE = " + Class.INSTANCE);
        System.out.println("Interface.INSTANCE = " + Interface.INSTANCE);
    }
}

interface Interface {
    Interface INSTANCE = Class.INSTANCE;

    default void func() { }
}

class Class implements Interface {
    public static final Class INSTANCE = new Class();
}
```

I run it using Java 17.0.7, `java Main.java` I get:

```
Class.INSTANCE = Class@5579bb86
Interface.INSTANCE = null
```

It looks like the `Interface.INSTANCE` is not initialized properly.
If I swap two printlns, I get the expected result:

```
Interface.INSTANCE = Class@5579bb86
Class.INSTANCE = Class@5579bb86
```

Also If I remove the default method in `Interface` (from the first code snippet) everything works fine as well and no null is printed.

What is happening here? More specifically I have three questions:

1. Why does the first code snippet prints null?
2. Why don't the second and third code snippet print null?

I know it probably has something to do with circular dependencies, but I want to know what happens exactly at the JVM level.

P.S. Question title suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specified in the JLS ([§9.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3.1), [§12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)):

> **Initialization of Fields in Interfaces**
>
> At run time, the initializer is evaluated and the field assignment performed exactly once, when the interface is initialized.

> **When Initialization Occurs**
>
> When a class is initialized, its superclasses are initialized (if they have not been previously initialized), as well as any superinterfaces that declare any `default` methods (if they have not been previously initialized).

It specifically says "superinterfaces that declare any `default` methods" because those `default` methods can be called from the instance constructor:

```
class Class implements Interface {
    public static final Class INSTANCE = new Class();
    Class() {
        func(); // this default method could use the interface's static fields!
    }
}
```

According to the Detailed Initialisation Procedures found in the [next section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), the interfaces are actually initialised before the field initialisers in the class are executed (See step 7 and step 9).

> 7. Next, if C is a class rather than an interface, then let SC be its superclass and let SI1, ..., SIn be all superinterfaces of C that
>    declare at least one default method.
>
>    For each S in the list [ SC, SI1, ..., SIn ], if S has not yet been initialized, then recursively perform this entire procedure for S

> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
>    in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Furthermore, if the class is in the middle of being initialised, nothing should be done (see step 3).

> 3. If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for initialization. Release LC and complete normally.

So when you first access `Class.INSTANCE`, `Class` is initialised. In this process, `Interface` is first fully initialised (because it has a default method). At this point `Class.INSTANCE` is not initialised yet, hence assigning `null` to `INSTANCE`. Then, the field initialisers in `Class` gets executed.

If you first access `Interface.INSTANCE`, `Interface` gets initialised and its field initialisers run. The field initialiser for `Interface.INSTANCE` accesses `Class.INSTANCE` *for the first time*, and so causes the initialisation of `Class`. This causes `Class.INSTANCE` to be assigned a non-null value. Remember that we are still running the field initialisers of `Interface`! After the full initialisation of `Class`, `Interface.INSTANCE` gets the non-null value.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed and precise answer! Just to make sure, can I presume this way of defining things is wrong (design wise)? I'm working on a code that has a similar structure. It's better to refactor it then?

Comment: @ParSal Yeah, I would not write code like this. Just have *one* field, and write static getters to get that field.